# Negation in AngularJS expression.

Tags: angularjs

I have one very noob question for AngularJS expressions. 
I want to check in expression (ngIf in this case) that something is 
undefined. Eg:

```
data-ng-if="typeof obj.property == 'undefined'"
```

How I can write expression to check this? 
I would be very grateful for any ideas and recommendations.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An undefined property will always be falsy, so you don't have to check it specifically unless you only care that it is undefined.  A simply check could then be

```
data-ng-if="!user.email"
```

That would evaluate to true unless the user object had the property email with non-falsy value (0,'',undefined are all false).  Maybe that is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the negation operator:

```
data-ng-if="!(typeof obj.property == 'undefined')"
```

Also your call to `typeof` is a noop, it does nothing. You can simply remove it:

```
data-ng-if="!(obj.property == 'undefined')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agreee with #Matt Pileggi
but just to playing around

```
if('prop' in obj)
```